# i am not able to make a selected node to bold in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-md" onclick="myBoldl()">Bold</button>

$('#jstree').jstree({
  core: {
    check_callback: true,
    data: [{
        "id": "1",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "PKM"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "parent": "1",
        "text": "Deve"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "parent": "1",
        "text": "Test"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "parent": "1",
        "text": "Prod"
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: ["wholerow", "unique", "dnd", "sort", "state", "contextmenu", "contextmenubtn"]
}).on("ready.jstree", function(e, data) {
  data.instance.open_all();
});

$('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) {
  var i, j, r = [];

  for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
    r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
  }

}).jstree();

function myBoldl() {
  $("#jstree").toggleClass("bold");
}
```

Comment: try $("#jstree").children().each(function(i){ $(this).addClass("bold");}) or try  $("#jstree").addClass("bold");

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap, but it does not a class called "bold". However it does have a class "font-weight-bold", which you can use.[Read here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#font-weight-and-italics)